# Ubuntu password no longer works after login

Tags: linux, passwords, login, sudo, ubuntu-22.04

I recently installed Ubuntu 22.04 on a laptop and something weird happened to my password. I can only use it to login when I select a user (the booting GUI) and after that, things like `sudo` or password pop-ups don't work (the system claims I provide a wrong password). Some other observations:

- the  user is a member of the sudo group (`groups`)
- login as the root user doesn't work either (`su -`), the only option here is the recover mode where the root's password works
- it happens for every new user I create (using the recovery mode) - new users work normally for a while then the problem reoccurs
- neither x11 nor wayland works
- `passwd` (recovery mode) doesn't help

EDIT - Recreating the user's home directory helps, but after a while the problem comes back.

Comment: Can you verify that the user you created, is in the sudo group, by using root?  Are you able to login as root? [Edit] your question instead of submitting a temporary comment.

Comment: I updated the description

Comment: When you say you recently installed Ubuntu 22.04, I assume this means, you update a previous installation of Ubuntu to 22.04.  If that isn't the case it sounds like you should simply reinstall Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: No, I got a new laptop with Win 11. I partitioned the disk and installed Ubuntu 22.04 in dual boot from scratch.

Comment: SInce it does not appear you have an actual working system, are you opposed to simply trying to reinstall Ubuntu?

Comment: I reinstalled the system (along with purging Ubuntu partitions) and it happens again. It looks like there's some update in the background that messes the password/some tokens. Btw, I added a small update to the description.